# init script issue: unexpected then, expecting }

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have an init script (im running Debian) to start serviio a DLNA server. When i go to start the service i get the following error. Any help would be appreciated. Please note: I'm VERY new to linux/bash/debian.

I get this error: Invalid Syntax: unexpected then on line 43, expected }

With this code:

```
                    #! /bin/sh
            #
            # /etc/init.d/serviio
            #
            #
            ### BEGIN INIT INFO
            # Provides: serviio
            # Required-Start: $network
            # Required-Stop: $network
            # Default-Start: 3 5
            # Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
            # Description: Start the serviio DLNA server in headless mode
            ### END INIT INFO

            SERVIIO_HOME="/opt/serviio"
            SERVIIO_DAEMON="serviio.sh"
            SERVIIO_BIN="$SERVIIO_HOME/bin/$SERVIIO_DAEMON"
            SERVIIO_USER="serviio"

            # Source function library.
            . /lib/lsb/init-functions

            RETVAL=0

            check() {
                    # Check that we're a privileged user
                    [ $(id -u) = 0 ] || exit 4

                    # Check if SERVIIO_HOME exists
                    test -d "$SERVIIO_HOME" || exit 5

                    # Check if SERVIIO_BIN is executable
                    test -x "$SERVIIO_BIN" || exit 5
            }

            start() {
                    check

                    echo -n "Starting Serviio DLNA server: "
                    /usr/bin/sudo -u $SERVIIO_USER -H $SERVIIO_BIN -headless &

                    RETVAL=$?
                    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
                        touch /var/lock/serviio
                        log_end_msg 0
                    else
                        log_end_msg 1
                    fi
                    echo
                    return $RETVAL
            }

            stop() {
                    check

                    echo -n "Shutting down Serviio DLNA daemon: "
                    killproc "$SERVIIO_BIN"
                    RETVAL=$?
                    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/serviio
                    echo
                    return $RETVAL
            }

            restart() {
                    stop
                    start
            }


            case "$1" in
            start)
                    start
                    ;;
            stop)
                    stop
                    ;;
            force-reload)
                    restart
                    ;;
            restart)
                    restart
                    ;;
            condrestart)
                    if [ -f /var/lock/serviio ]; then
                        restart
                    fi
                    ;;
            status)
                    status serviio.sh
                    ;;
            *)
                    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|force-reload}"
                    RETVAL=2
            esac

            exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Try running your script with `sh -x` in order to see what the shell is doing in detail. This way you can check, for instance, if a variable is not expanding in the way you expected, which may confuse the shell.

Comment: It seems that the `-x` option does not expand function calls. If you want to debug only a specific function you can use `set -x` to enable debugging mode when the function starts and `set +x ` to disable it when it completes.

Answer (score 1):

I can run this script without getting syntax errors,, but I don't have serviio installed. Anyway, my guess would be that $RETVAL is somehow empty, and that it needs to be in quotes:

```
if [ "$RETVAL" -eq 0 ]; then
```

Although I would think that would complain about '[' expecting a unary operator.

The next thing to try would be to comment out sections at a time by prepending "#" to the lines in the section until you can narrow down where the problem is. For example, comment out the whole "start" section, or comment out the "check" function (and make sure you comment out the calls to it, too). That should help narrow it down.